# SSRS 2008R2: Can not edit or modify the X-axis label in line chart

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS world. I want to show the Horizontal axis label field as per below:

In my report I will pass a parameter called Year. In the repot it will show a line in Y-axis (it is limit field) and Date field is in the X-axis. I want to show total (12 + 1)=13 label like 1st date of every month (e.g. 1-jan-, 1-Feb) and last date of the selected year (31 -Dec).

Can anyone please help me regarding that?

Comment: Try to amplify your question, it is not clear

Comment: For the Horizontal axis the label interval is 1 and interval type is 'Months'. So there will be 12 labels (1-Jan-2012,1-Feb-2012) in the x-axis. But I want to add one extra label in it at the end of the Axis (like 31-Dec-2012). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the axis type to **scalar**, then set the following fields:

- Minimum - 1
- Maximum - 13
- Interval - 1
- Interval Type - Numbers

Comment: This is not working. The X-axis field is date field. And the Interval is 1 and interval type is 'Month'. This is working fine. I am getting 12 label by that. But I just want to add an extra label at the end of the X-axis. Is it possible?